# confusionMatrix() caret package in R - what is happening under the hood in the Class 3 Example on the help screen?

Tags: r, knn, confusion-matrix, caret

In the R help page for confusionMatrix() in the caret package there is this 3 class example:

```
confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))

newPrior <- c(.05, .8, .15)
names(newPrior) <- levels(iris$Species)

confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
```

How is the newPrior value getting incorporated into the Confusion Matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `newPrior` is not included in the error confusion matrices in any way!!

You may have been confused that the two matrices are different. However, this is due to the pseudo-random nature of the `sample` function. If you add the grain alignment before each call, you will find that in both cases the confusion matrices are identical!

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
cf1 = confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))

newPrior <- c(.05, .8, .15)
names(newPrior) <- levels(iris$Species)

set.seed(123)
cf2 = confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))

identical(cf1, cf2)
```

output

```
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Marek - that makes sense.  I wonder why is this example even in the help section?